# Jacoco code coverage does not include my app module in multi modules android project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using Jacoco in order to generate a HTML report of the code coverage by unit tests or instrumented tests.

My android project is composed of several modules:

- app (the android application);
- custom-calendarview (lib);
- iotcam (lib);
- qrcodereaderview (lib);
- singledateandtimepicker (lib).

Using this tutorial : https://proandroiddev.com/unified-code-coverage-for-android-revisited-44789c9b722f and this example : https://github.com/rafaeltoledo/unified-code-coverage-android/blob/mixed-languages/jacoco.gradle I wrote the following code:

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"

jacoco
{
  toolVersion = "0.8.5"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
  jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
}

task executeUnitAndIntegrationTestsAndCreateReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testQaUnitAndIntegrationTestsDebugUnitTest', 'createQaUnitAndIntegrationTestsDebugCoverageReport']) {
  reports
  {
    xml.enabled = true
    html.enabled = true
    html.destination file("${rootProject.buildDir}/coverage-report")
  }

  def javaClasses = []
  def kotlinClasses = []
  def javaSrc = []
  def kotlinSrc = []
  def execution = []

  def fileFilter = [
  '**/R.class',
  '**/R$*.class',
  '**/BuildConfig.*',
  '**/Manifest*.*',
  '**/*Test*.*',
  'androidx/**/*.*',
  ]

  rootProject.subprojects.each { proj ->
    println "current proj: $proj"

    javaClasses << fileTree(dir: "$proj.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    kotlinClasses << fileTree(dir: "$proj.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    javaSrc << "$proj.projectDir/src/main/java"
    kotlinSrc << "$proj.projectDir/src/main/kotlin"
    execution << fileTree(dir: proj.buildDir,
    includes: ['**/*.exec', '**/*.ec'])
  }

  println "javaSrc: $javaSrc"
  println "kotlinSrc: $kotlinSrc"

  sourceDirectories.from = files([javaSrc, kotlinSrc])
  classDirectories.from = files([javaClasses, kotlinClasses])

  print execution

  executionData.from = files(execution)

  doLast() {
    print "${reports.html.destination}/index.html"
  }
```

According to the logs, all modules are taken in considerations into the `javaSrc` and the `kotlinSrc` variables:

JavaSrc: [
  C:\mypath\app/src/main/java, 
  C:\mypath\custom-calendarview/src/main/java, 
  C:\mypath\iotcam/src/main/java, 
  C:\mypath\qrcodereaderview/src/main/java, 
  C:\mypath\singledateandtimepicker/src/main/java
]

kotlinSrc: [
  C:\mypath\app/src/main/kotlin, 
  C:\mypath\custom-calendarview/src/main/kotlin, 
  C:\mypath\iotcam/src/main/kotlin, 
  C:\mypath\qrcodereaderview/src/main/kotlin, 
  C:\mypath\singledateandtimepicker/src/main/kotlin
]

[
  directory 'C:\mypath\app\build', 
  directory 'C:\mypath\custom-calendarview\build', 
  directory 'C:\mypath\iotcam\build', 
  directory 'C:\mypath\qrcodereaderview\build', 
  directory 'C:\mypath\singledateandtimepicker\build'
]

Finally, the code coverage report is correctly generated, but it contains the package name of ALL submodules excepted the "app" one :

[image]

Note, if I click on the "sessions" link, I can found all the classes of the "app" module.

How can I add my "app" module to this report?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacoco works perfectly using this plugin : https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin